# Sending a HTML file (with images) as email body using command line

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, email, mime-types

This seems like a basic question and there are variations of it. I have a ONE-COLUMN html file (let us call it status.html).

I would like to send this file which has a few images as the BODY of an email. I would like to do this using the Linux command line, but I am unsure of how to proceed. I do not know how the images will get gobbled up and formatted accordingly (i.e. are the base64 or attachments).

The key part is that I want the images in the HTML file to be in the body of the email ...

Is the a way or a Linux tool that does just this?

<<<

Comment: `echo "and have a good day" | mutt you@some.where  -m "the page" -a file.html img*.jpg`?

Comment: Thanks JJoao - I do not think this is the answer I am looking for. 

A HTML file would naturally include images (with the IMG tag). I am not interested in separately processing the images. 

I am though, would be interested in a tool that handles this, otherwise I may have to write my own tool (and base64 any images).

Comment: JJoao's suggestion using the Mutt mailclient is correct.  Also, please clarify what you mean with "one-column HTML file".  A HTML file is a text file and does not contain images; it merely references them via IMG tags.  So if you are looking for a solution where you send a single HTML file and it contains images, this won't happen.

Comment: You are correct 

"-a" Attach a file to your message using MIME.  When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses with  "--"  is  mandatory,  e.g.  mutt  -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2.  The -a option must be placed at the end of command line options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-a" Attach a file to your message using MIME. When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g.

```
mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2.
```

The -a option must be placed at the end of command line options. –